# Writing a CSV to ftp

Tags: c#, web-services, csv, ftp

I have a webservice that compiles data together and i would like to store it in a CSV so the user can be given a download link to get it. this is what i have

```
            string fileName = "Test.csv";
            string ftpAddress = "MYDOMAIN.COM";
            string username = "MYUSERNAME";
            string password = "MYPASSWORD";

            List<string[]> done = new List<string[]>();
            string[] firstline = new string[2];

            firstline[0] = "hello this is ";
            firstline[1] = "a test";
            done.Add(firstline);
            string[] secondline = new string[2];

            secondline[0] = "hello this is a ";
            secondline[1] = "second test";
            done.Add(secondline);
            string delimiter = ",";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++)
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, done[index]));

            string str = sb.ToString();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + fileName);
                request.ContentType = 

                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                reqStream.Close();
```

The CSV saves correct but i do not get the separate columns it reads

"hello this is ,a test"
"hello this is a ,second test"

rather then

"hello this is ","a test"
"hello this is a ","second test"

any ideas on how to get the comma to separate the columns?

Comment: Well where in your code are you expecting it to put the quotes in?

Comment: I dont want quotes, but line one is all in cell a1 rather than split between a1 and a2. my bad way of explaining it

Comment: Concentrate on what you want to *be in the file*. It's just a text file, after all. Once you've worked out what the text file needs to look like to open correctly in whatever you're using, then making the code write the appropriate text file is simple. It's not clear why you think the FTP part is relevant, either.

Comment: do not use index < 2. use Count for instance. apart of that, in firstling[0] and secondline[0] a comma could be placed according to your code and your explanation.

Comment: to answer your question 1:1 - secondline[0] = "hello this is a " + ",";

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code to match your requirements:

```
        string fileName = "Test.csv";
        string ftpAddress = "MYDOMAIN.COM";
        string username = "MYUSERNAME";
        string password = "MYPASSWORD";
        

        List<string[]> done = new List<string[]>();
        string[] firstline = new string[2];

        firstline[0] = "hello this is ";
        firstline[1] = "a test";
        done.Add(firstline);
        string[] secondline = new string[2];

        secondline[0] = "hello this is a ";
        secondline[1] = "second test";
        done.Add(secondline);
        string delimiter = @""",""";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var lineArray in done)           
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format(@"""{0}""", string.Join(delimiter, lineArray)));

        string str = sb.ToString();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + fileName);
        request.ContentType =

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        reqStream.Close();
```

Variable str now contains:

> "hello this is ","a test"
>
> "hello this is a ","second test"

If you use a semikolon instead of comma excel displays the file correctly.

```
string delimiter = @""";""";
```